# Prevent Wget from downloading items with long filenames

Tags: bash, wget

I have shell script that uses Wget to download webpages and other resources from a list of urls I have stored in `urls.csv`

Here's the script.

```
todays_date=$(date '+%F')
INPUT=urls.csv
IFS=';'
while read url user
do
    url=$(echo $url | cut -c 2-)
    url=$(echo $url | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)
    user=$(echo $user | cut -c 2-)
    user=$(echo $user | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)
    user=$(echo ${user%?})
    mkdir -p ./$user/$todays_date
    echo "Grabbing $url ..."
    wget --page-requisites --convert-links --no-clobber -T 240  $url -P ./$user/$todays_date
done <$INPUT
```

This script has resulted in downloading files with names over 260 charecters.  This is a [problem](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7) when I move the files to my Windows computer.  Is there a way to truncate the file names or have Wget ignore items with long filenames?

Comment: Those string manipulations are ghastly.  Using `echo` without quoting the argument is going to come back and bite you one day, but chomping off quotation marks (that's what you are doing with the `cut`s there, right?) could be done simply and elegantly by preprocessing the input a little bit with `sed`, in which case no `echo` will be necessary.

Comment: sed `s/^"\([^"]*\)";"\([^"]*\)"/\1 \2/' | while read -r url user;`... provided your input doesn't contain any spaces.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the tip!  I will test the script with the modification.

Comment: Can you give some example filenames that wget produces, and what you would like them to be?